# Using chdir with an absolute path

Tags: php, chdir

I am trying to use chdir inside a function which writes & saves a file. If I try to write the file to a nearby folder e.g. 'bins' like so:

```
$location = 'bins';
chdir($location);
```

then it works fine and the files are written and placed into the bins folder. The problem I have is that I need to save the files onto a different drive like so:

```
$location = 'I:/directory/test/'
chdir($location);
```

but when I use an absolute path like above I get this error message:

```
Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in index.php on line 586
```

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it please?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. there is no point to use chdir() to save a file. just prepend file path with $location.
2. chdir accepts absolute paths as well, so, there is indeed something wrong with given path. double-check it

Comment: Maybe it would be a wise decision to use realpath() too.

Comment: This answers the OP problem, but not the question in the title. Thus, it is useless for all those who find the page by the title, including Google searches.

Comment: @dotancohen there is not a single problem with using chdir with absolute paths as well.